# Can I embed the scaled method for a QPixmap derived class?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpixmap

I would like to have each `QPixmap` derived object at the wanted size upon creation. Let's say I have this fictional class:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <QPixmap>

#include <QString>

class MyPixmap : public QPixmap
{
public:
    enum class Size { icon, veryVerySmall, medium, large };
    static int toInt(Size size);

    MyPixmap (QString fileName, Size size);
    const QString& getPath();
private:
    QString m_fileName; //
    Size m_size;
};
```

```cpp
#include "MyPixmap.h"
#include "MyGraphicsScene.h"

int MyPixmap::toInt(Size size)
{
    switch (size)
    {
    case MyPixmap::Size::icon:
        return 20;
    case MyPixmap::Size::veryVerySmall:
        return MyGraphicsScene::size / 20;
    case MyPixmap::Size::medium:
        return MyGraphicsScene::size / 32;
    case MyPixmap::Size::large:
        return MyGraphicsScene::size / 40;
    default:
        throw std::exception{ "Unreachable code reached" };
    }
}

MyPixmap::MyPixmap(QString fileName, Size /* size*/)
    :
    m_fileName{ fileName }
{
    load("PATH/TO/FOLDER/" + fileName + ".png");
    // scaled(size, size);
}

const QString& MyPixmap::getPath()
{
    return m_piece;
}
```

So I could execute this code:

```
#include "MyPixmap.h"

int main()
{
   MyPixmap myPixmap{ "Butterfly", MyPixmap::Size::veryVerySmall };
   // pass myPixmap to various functions and objects
   return 0;
}
```

Scaling inside the constructor won't work, since `scaled` is a `static` function. Alternatively, I could overload `QPixamp scaled()`, like this:

```cpp
QPixmap PiecePixmap::scaled()
{
    int intSize{ toInt(m_size) };
    return scaled(intSize, intSize);
}
```

However, then I'm still not using the actual `MyPixmap` object.

Is it possible to scale the pixmap inside the class itself, or is overloading `scaled` as suggested my best shot to force a certain piece to be of internally hardcoded size?

<sub>*Note: I heavily edited this post, so to see the Monopoly example, check the edit history. The current question code has not been tested, since it's for demonstration-purposes only.*</sub>

Comment: You are probably looking for `PiecePixmap::PiecePixmap(QString pawn, int size ) : QPixmap(QPixmap(":/QtMonopoly...").scaled(size, size)) {}`

Comment: Looking at your code I wonder if you really need all that stuff. Which one is true in your case: "A piece IS A pixmap" or "A piece HAS A pixmap"? Think about that.

Comment: Since I would like to encapsulate the sizes, I'm going to stick with that class, which it was meant for after all. Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: @scopchanov, I rewrote the question, but I'm not sure if you understood the previous example. Anyway, the `PiecePixmap` was used in (for example) the `PawnPixmapItem`, which is a view class for the `Pawn` model class and other Model-View classes, only to be a small wrapper around the `QPixmap`; and `PawnPixmapItem` has indeed a `PiecePixmap`, but I understand it wasn't clear what the `PiecePixmap was made for, that's why I generalized the question. Also, one could argue that path-encapsulation and pre-set sizes are still not sufficient to put it in a class indeed. I just saw we misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Igor Tandetnik* stated, it's possible to create an immediately scaled pixmap by calling the `scaled` method and passing its return value to a copy constructor as follows:

```cpp
MyPixmap::MyPixmap(QString path, int height, int length)
    : QPixmap{ QPixmap{ path }.scaled(size, size) }
{
}
```